# What is the Android/Java corresponding method to the C# Stream object method Write()?

Tags: c#, java, android, sockets, stream

A snippet of the [code](http://wiki.mikrotik.com/wiki/API_in_C_Sharp) that I want to translate is here:

```
class MK
    {   
        Stream connection;
        TcpClient con;

        public MK(string ip)
        {
            con = new TcpClient();
            con.Connect(ip, 8728);
            connection = (Stream)con.GetStream();
        }
        public void Close()
        {
            connection.Close();
            con.Close();
        }
        public bool Login(string username, string password)
        {
            Send("/login", true);
            string hash = Read()[0].Split(new string[] { "ret=" }, StringSplitOptions.None)[1];
            Send("/login");
            Send("=name=" + username);
            Send("=response=00" + EncodePassword(password, hash), true);
            if (Read()[0] == "!done")
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        public void Send(string co)
        {
            byte[] bajty = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(co.ToCharArray());
            byte[] velikost = EncodeLength(bajty.Length);

            connection.Write(velikost, 0, velikost.Length);
            connection.Write(bajty, 0, bajty.Length);
        }
        public void Send(string co, bool endsentence)
        {
            byte[] bajty = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(co.ToCharArray());
            byte[] velikost = EncodeLength(bajty.Length);
            connection.Write(velikost, 0, velikost.Length);
            connection.Write(bajty, 0, bajty.Length);
            connection.WriteByte(0);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equivalent of `Stream.Write` is [`OutputStream.write`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html#write%28byte%5b%5d,%20int,%20int%29)... but it's not clear whether that will be enough to help you. (It's also not clear why your current code is using `Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(co.ToCharArray())` instead of just `Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(co)`

Comment: I am honored to receive your reply, thanks for helping. Edit: Should I obtain more information with regards to your questions, I will comment here.